# Rcpp modules method overloading

Tags: r, rcpp

Is there a Rcpp Modules "internal" (or say correct) way how to export overloaded methods?

The [Rcpp-modules vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf) still has a "TODO" on providing a good example (in section 2.2.5 it says "TODO: mention overloading, need good example.").

I can export my overloaded methods following [this](https://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2010-November/001326.html) solution from Romain François, however, issues can occur with the provided solutions. E.g.:

```r
library(Rcpp)

# define example class in C++
sourceCpp(code = paste0('
#include<Rcpp.h>
class Test {
    private:
    int a;
    public:
    Test(): a{0} {};
    Test(int x): a{x} {};
    int foo();
    int foo(int x);
};
int Test::foo() {
    return a;
}
int Test::foo(int x) {
    return a + x;
}
RCPP_MODULE(rawdata_module) {',
# solution 1 to handle member function overloading provided in
# https://lists.r-forge.r-project.org/pipermail/rcpp-devel/2010-November/001326.html
'    int (Test::*foo1)(int x) = &Test::foo;
    int (Test::*foo0)() = &Test::foo;
    Rcpp::class_<Test>( "Test" )
        .constructor()
        .constructor<int>()',
# works: foo with 1 argument before 0 arguments!
'       .method("foo", foo1)
        .method("foo", foo0)',
# solution 2 (also working) 
#works: foo with 1 argument before 0 arguments!
'       //.method("foo", ( int (Test::*)(int) )(&Test::foo) )
        //.method("foo", ( int (Test::*)() )(&Test::foo) )
        ;
}
'))

# create new object in R
obj0 <- Test$new()
obj1 <- Test$new(5L)

# test overloading
obj0$foo()
obj0$foo(3L)

obj1$foo()
obj1$foo(3L)
```

For both solutions, if we export the method with 0 arguments before foo with one argument (foo0 before foo1 in solution 1), the code compiles fine and we can call both functions from R, however only method foo with 0 arguments is called.

Thx & please be patient with me. I'd call myself rather inexperienced in C++...

Compiler info:

```
gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110
```

R session info:

```
R version 4.2.0 (2022-04-22)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Progress Linux 6.99 (fuchur-backports)

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3   colorout_1.2-2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0         tools_4.2.0            codetools_0.2-18       RhpcBLASctl_0.21-247.1
```

Comment: Tricky. Maybe most of what you need / want are in the old email you referenced. Maybe the trick with the 'valid' helper method can help?   I think in general I would not expect too much here as there are differences between function signatures in R and C/C++ so perfect mapping to something that exists full well in C++ may be not possible in R.

Comment: So, did I misinterpret the note in the vignette saying "TODO: mention overloading, need good example."... I thought this means, that a correct way exists and documentation will be added to the vignette soon... :-)

Comment: Ah, no, I don't think that extrapolation works, sadly!   Modules is rather cool for what it does but also hard to extent / now somewhat stale.  "What you see is what you" is probably a fair description.